# Cast Error: Cast to String failed for value when try to find it

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I got very strange problem here, I can save data through mongoose but cannot do the query.
Here is the code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

const CategorySchema = new Schema({
  store : {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  categories : [{
    parent : String,
    name : String,
  }],
});

CategorySchema.index({store: 1, update_at: -1});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

When I try to do the query, I get this error:

> (node:7412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise 
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): ValidationError: CastError: Cast to 
>   String failed for value "{ _id: 58dd019b1a06731b0990b878,   store:
>   'Store-Name-Here',   categories: [],   __v: 0 }" at path "store"

I got very similar schema for other collections, they work fine but not this one.

This is how I do the query:

```
Category.findOne({store: 'Store-Name-Here'}).exec().then(result => console.log(result), err => console.log(err));
```

And

```
Category.find().exec(function(err, result) {
    if (err)
        return next(err);
    console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: how did you query it? pls add the function

Comment: Category.findOne({store: 'Store-Name-Here'}).then(store => {/*something here*/}, err => {/*err here*/});

Comment: once try, `Category.findOne({store: "Store"}).then(store => {/*something here*/}, err => {/*err here*/});`, and check what happens

Comment: It returns null

Comment: error is gone? while you give that?

Comment: Yep, no err when try to find something doesn't exist.

Comment: The issue may be  `'Store-Name-Here'` or even the handling of the api success call back

Comment: First try using double quote, or some name which does not have `-`(dash)

Comment: Yea, but I got a very similar one which searching on exactly the same string and api success call back, and It works fine.

Comment: so, handling may have an issue, the error is pointing to which line number?

Comment: The error will come out only when I try the correct one like: Category.find() or Category.findOne(). No matter when I try to search all of them or a specific one.

Comment: No line number shows in error message, I have pasted all of them here.

Comment: I think the output comes as an array, but you are handling it as a string. Paste the handling of code

Comment: Category.findOne({store: 'Store-Name-Here'}).exec().then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      return res.status(200).json({'message': result});
    }, err => next(err));

Comment: `Category.findOne({store: 'Store-Name-Here'}).exec().then(result => { console.log(result);}, err => next(err)); `, just `console.log(result)` and check if error persists

Comment: Yes, still here.

Comment: The reposne is coming to `success`  or `error`?

Comment: @qwang is `'Store-Name-Here'` _literally_ the value you are querying, or are you passing some sort of variable containing that string? It looks very much like you are passing a Mongoose document instead of a string. Also, do you have any hooks/middleware for the `Category` model?

Comment: @Sravan The request will just keep going until time out.

Comment: @robertklep 'Store-Name-Here' is exectly the value I used. Because it's just for test. And no other middleware for the model.

Comment: The request url is api.localhost:3000/store/Store-Name-Here/categories/, receive by router.get('/store/:storename/categories', Category.list)

Comment: @qwang could it be that the document in the database is broken? That the `store` property of the document is an object instead of a string?

Comment: I don't think so, because you can see the document has been output from database. It is a string definitely.

Comment: The issue may be with promise handling, just in place of `exec()`, try two call back functions for `success` and `error`.  like, `function(){}`

Comment: @Sravan handling the exception doesn't fix the _cause_ of the problems.

Comment: @qwang can you add the output of the following (run from the MongoDB shell) to your question: `db.categories.find({ store: 'Store-Name-Here' })` (or even, if there are only a few documents in the database, `db.categories.find()`)

Comment: @robertklep, I am not trying to handle the exception, I am trying to find where the exception is coming from.

Comment: @Sravan Mongoose is trying to cast an object (or a Mongoose document, not sure) to string, and failing. It's a result of the queries being shown, which leads me to believe that there might be an incorrect document in the database (since we basically ruled out all other possibilities).

Comment: I think I find the problem. I tried to add a static method to category scheme named CategoryScheme.static.init(). After I removed that method, everything works fine. I think maybe there already had a method named init() for some reasons, and I created one may override it. That cause the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem. I tried to add a static method to category scheme named `CategoryScheme.static.init()`. After I removed that method, everything works fine. I think maybe there was already a method named `init()` for some reason, and I created one that may have overrode it. That's what caused the error.